# Retrieve xml data using phonegap

Tags: xml, cordova

I am building an android app using phonegap. I want to retrieve xml data from my host server to android app. My XML File: http://www.guitarmaddy.com/index.php?option=com_dmxmlexport&catid=8 . I want to get all  tag content and display in phonegap app.

Previously I used:

$(document).ready(function(){

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
    url: "www.guitarmaddy.com/index.php?option=com_dmxmlexport&catid=8",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {

        alert("reading xml");


    }
});

});
```

but it is not working.. alert message is not coming..
Please suggest me links, I want to know the basics of retrieving xml data.

Comment: Have you whitelisted www.guitarmaddy.com in the PhoneGap project config?

Comment: Yes, I have whitelisted with code: <access origin="http://www.guitarmaddy.com" />

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
    url: "www.guitarmaddy.com/index.php?option=com_dmxmlexport&catid=8",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {

        alert("reading xml");


    }
});
}
```

Does that solve the problem?

Comment: Well Keeping this code inside onDeviceReady is not working. But I solved the problem.. I did change the name from index.html to main.html and created a new index.html which redirected to main.html . I am unsure of logic behind it, but it solved the problem.

Comment: Really, dont know why it happened